# Xcode reinstall device types

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios-simulator, xcrun

I removed all the device related installations from my Xcode as I thought I wouldn't need it. Now I have to reinstall some parts of it to develop with react-native.

I could easily install the latest runtime again but the list of devicetypes (`xcrun simctl list devicetypes`) returns nothing. Thanks to that I am not able to create a new simulator.

How can I add back selected device types?

Btw the old runtimes with devices can be list with `xcrun simctl list devices` although they are not available (runtime profile not found)

[image]

Comment: "I removed all the device related installations from my Xcode" How, exactly?

Comment: `cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/` then `sudo rm -rf AppleTV* Watch* iPhone*`

Comment: Yes, I was afraid that was what you meant. :) So you maimed Xcode and now you regret it? Why not just reinstall Xcode?

Comment: I thought there would be an easier way ;), but apparently I have no better choice.

Comment: What could be easier than click the download link? :) It's here somewhere: https://developer.apple.com/download/

Comment: Unless of course you saved off a copy of Xcode to an external drive — I _always_ do. You never know when you'll need an old version after all.

Comment: Well, reinstalling the runtime was pretty easy. It could be the same for the device type ;)

Comment: We obviously have very different ideas of what's "easy"! Or sane, for that matter. Why anyone would reach inside Xcode for any reason beats me.

Comment: If you install all the shit (tv, watch, phone, pad, etc.) with a couple of runtimes it can eat up 10gigs...... But you are right. I could have been more careful by only removing the old runtimes from the GUI.

Comment: If I had to worry about 10GB I'd be in the wrong business. It's the price of entry. Shrug.

Comment: Haha. Well, the country I am originally from that $250 is the 1/3 of the average net salary ;) Thanks for your answers anyway.